# Capitalize name of parent directory in vs code user snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am creating a user snippet in vs code for my react development.

I have one transform to extract immediate parent folder name using

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/^.+\\\\(.*)$/$1/}
```

and another transform to capitalize

```
"${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}"
```

Link : [How to get the base directory in visual studio code snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366014/how-to-get-the-base-directory-in-visual-studio-code-snippet)

I am still a noob at this so trying to figure out how to extract capitalized immediate parent folder name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out !

I took help from this [How to apply more than on transform on visual studio code snippets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969228/how-to-apply-more-than-on-transform-on-visual-studio-code-snippets?rq=1)

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/^.+\\\\(.*)$/${1:/capitalize}/}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use here:

```
${1:${TM_DIRECTORY/^.*(\\/|\\\\)([^(\\/|\\\\)]+)$/${2:/capitalize}/}}
```